# Several PHP packages in Ubuntu, how to only use the latest version?

Tags: server, php

I suspect that my Ubuntu server contains abandon PHP files or packages which is not used. How can I do a clean install of latest PHP 5.6 in my server?

I ran this on my ubuntu server '`dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall`' and got this below.

```
php-common                                      install
php5                                            install
php5-cli                                        install
php5-common                                     install
php5-curl                                       install
php5-fpm                                        install
php5-gd                                         install
php5-intl                                       install
php5-json                                       install
php5-mcrypt                                     install
php5-mysqlnd                                    install
php5-readline                                   install
php5-tidy                                       install
php5-xmlrpc                                     install
php5-xsl                                        install
php5.6                                          install
php5.6-cli                                      install
php5.6-common                                   install
php5.6-fpm                                      install
php5.6-json                                     install
php5.6-mbstring                                 install
php5.6-mcrypt                                   install
php5.6-mysql                                    install
php5.6-opcache                                  install
php5.6-readline                                 install
```

It seem like there are several duplicated PHP files there.

Furthermore, on my phpmyadmin, I saw that I'm using an older PHP 5.6 version 
"`PHP version: 5.6.23-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`"

However, when I run `php -v`, it shows this below:

```
PHP 5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

This seems like my server is using different PHP version on different environment.

How can I remove the unwanted PHP files and use only the latest version of PHP 5.6? I'm not able to experiment it myself because it's a production server, I can't afford to make it down for more than 10-20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:

```
apt-get purge php5-common
```